# Highcharts : Chart with drilldown how to obtain click event of drill up button

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts wtih drilldown and here is my working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Dg33R/).

**How can I get the click event of the drill up button ?** I have referred the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.drillUp)
but can't figure out how can I incorporate this into my code.

I want to do something like:

```
drillUp: function(){
     //get point details by using something like this or this.point
     //get series details by using something like point.series
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to catch the [`event`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events). See the [`chart.events.drillup`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drillup) API doc.
To get the series and points in the series you would do something like:

```
    events: {
        drillup: function (e) {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.options.series[0].name);
            console.log(this.options.series[0].data[0].name);
        }
    }
```

Since you did not state which series or points you wanted this is the most general method.

**Link to the updated [working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/LjUaz/)**

Comment: Thanks wergeld ! "A plus one" for you, but your answer is still incomplete. How can I get series and point details ?

Answer (score 1):

```
chart: {
         type: 'column',
         events: {
            drillup: function (e) {
                   alert(e.seriesOptions.name);
            }
        }     
    }
```

From the below line,

> e.seriesOptions.name

You will get the series name, which you are loading, by clicking that back button(drill up button).